Factorizing rotation matrix's quaternion representation
I'm to stabilise a system using a Lyapunov function, to do this I made the substituion below:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{f}\mathbf{R}(\boldsymbol{q}_{e})={\Psi}_{0}(q_{e0}-1)+\boldsymbol{\Psi}_{v}^T \boldsymbol{q}_{ev}
\end{equation}
Where $\boldsymbol{f}$ is a vector function, $q_{e0}$ is the scalar component of the unit quaternion error and $\boldsymbol{q}_{ev}$ the vector component. From this $\mathbf{R}(\boldsymbol{q}_e)$ is found as the error rotation matrix below:
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{R}(\boldsymbol{q}_e)=\left(q_{e0}^2-\|\boldsymbol{q}_{ev}\|^2\right)\mathbf{I}_3+2\boldsymbol{q}_{ev}\boldsymbol{q}_{ev}^T+2 q_{e0}[\boldsymbol{q}_{ev}]_\times
\end{equation}
I want to factorise the above expression for $\mathbf{R}(\boldsymbol{q}_e)$ to satisfy this expression ${\Psi}_{0}(q_{e0}-1)+\boldsymbol{\Psi}_{v}^T \boldsymbol{q}_{ev}$. I have tried for a while but, I don't know if this is possible.If it isnt possible, can you prove it, also what substitution can be made so that the factorisation can be made to satisfy:
\begin{equation}
{\Psi}_{0}(z_{e0}-1)+\boldsymbol{\Psi}_{v}^T \boldsymbol{z}_{ev}
\end{equation}
